# Closures of one-parameter subgroups of lie groups

Tags: differential-topology, lie-groups

I'm reading some basic facts of Lie groups. I meat with difficulties when I try to solve the following statement: *"Prove the closure of a non-closed one-parameter subgroup of a Lie group is a torus."*

I have proved that a compact connected abelian Lie group must be a torus. However, I have no idea how to show that the closure is compact. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide a counter-example that the closure isn't compact? Thanks.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I confused myself. I guess the statement is true.

Answer (score 8):

Let $\gamma:\mathbb R \to G$ denote the one parameter sub-group, and $H$ its image in $G$.
The closure $\overline H$ of $H$ is an abelian (connected) Lie group, and so can be written (non-canonically) in the form $\overline H = V \times T$, where $V$ is a vector-space and  $T$ a torus.  We want to show, if $H\not=\overline H$, that $V= 0$. Suppose $p=(v,t)\in\overline H \setminus H$. The projection of $\gamma$ on $V$ is of the form $x \mapsto xw$, for some non-zero $w\in V$ (non-zero, for otherwise $H$ is not dense in $\overline H$ (!), unless $V=0$), so there is an open neighborhood $B$ of $p$, with compact closure, and a bound $R$ such that $|x|>R$ implies $\gamma (x) \not \in \overline B$. The set $\gamma([-R,R])$ is compact, and contains $p$ in its closure, so contains $p$. Therefore $p\in H$. Contradiction! Therefore $V=0$.

Comment: Why does such a $B$ exist?

Comment: Because the linear map $ t \to wt$ goes to infinity: one can take $B = A \times T$, for some bounded open ball $A$ which contains $w$. For $t$ large $wt$ cannot belong to $\overline A$.

Comment: Why is $p$ contained in the closure of the image of that interval?

Comment: @INQUISITOR a quick word just to acknowledge your question but I'm 'out of office / on the road / whatever' until mid next week and I might not have a chance to think about it  until then ((and what an old post this one is!)... sorry! But if you do, feel free to comment before then, and if I forget in the interim, please 'reping' - best wishes!

Comment: @INQUISITOR I'm kinda zonked - but how does this look: $\overline B$ contains an open n'h'd of $p$, which by construction $\gamma ({\mathbb R }\setminus [-R, R] )$ does not intersect and thus does not have $p$ in its closure. On the other hand by hypothesis $\gamma \mathbb R$ has $p$ in its closure. Hence $\gamma ([-R, R])$ does.